# Border radius in thead and tfoot with background image

Tags: html, css, background, border

I have a table, inside thead, tbody and tfoot. Thead and tfoot have a background image.
I try to apply rounded corners, and everything looks good until I apply any background (color or image).

Screen below:

[image]

Thead and tfoot have also border, so when I hide background, it's rounded like I want...
The problem appears in all browsers...

Is there any option to round this background (color or image)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the background as an image with `z-index: 1` and set the content as `z-index: 2`, then round the image's corners using CSS.

Comment: yeah, works perfect, thanks. I set position of main div as relative, make two additional divs (background_top, background_bottom) and set them position: absolute. And create table inside main div because I need 100% width of table.